# loginhook for guest account mac

Tags: macos, authentication, hook, user-accounts

I need to make a login hook for the guest user in mac. This script simply copies an app in application folder to the desktop of Guest user. I have the following script and it works perfectly for any other user, i.e, for a user named VSI:

```
tell application "Finder"

copy file "iMac HD:Applications:mix.app" to folder "iMac HD:Users:VSI:Desktop"
end tell
```

for Guest user, I googled, and the script should be:

```
tell application "Finder"

copy file "iMac HD:Applications:mix.app" to folder "iMac HD:Users:Guest:Desktop"
end tell
```

How can I make it a login hook?

I tried changing the `/library/preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist` file, but I can't figure out how for the guest pc. I also changed the `/etc/ttys` file, but it is not making `mix.app` a login hook for all users.

Comment: …just out of curiosity: why exactly are you copying the Application  to the guest user´s desktop in the first place? Wouldn´t putting it into the Dock be enough?

Comment: a logout app that shows a user his charges after a user has used the pc. I would really want the app to be copied on the Guest account. Problem is all guest data is deleted once guest logs out. So i made a apple script that copies that app onto the desktop . Here is the code and i works perfectly.

tell application "Finder"
 
 copy file "iMac HD:Applications:testapp.app" to folder "iMac HD:Users:VSI:Desktop"
end tell
only issue is i cant figure out how it would work for guest pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done... i found the answer...simple... a loginhook or a logout hook is for a mac pc and is independant of user... thats it i guess